# How to change the property class for row in data blocks using oracle form builder?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to make the row change color when clicking on it. I want to change it using property pallete.

Answer (score 1):

*If your mean to paint an individual row of a Database Block with `"Number of Records Displayed" >0` ;*

- open up `Property Palette`,
- go to `Records` node,
- and toggle `"Current Record Visual Attribute Group"` then set as a
  `Visual Attribute` as you wish as previously created.